# How to write an image containing multiple partitions to a USB flash drive on Windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

On Windows, you can only see the first partition on removable media.  I want to write a C++ program that can write an image containing an MBR and 2 partitions of data to the USB flash drive.  I don't need the 2nd partition to be viewable in Windows- I just need to be able to write this raw image to the USB flash drive from Windows/C++ such that later, when run on Linux, the 2 partitions can be seen.

I have read about installing a filter driver that would end up treating the removable media as fixed, which would be nice for reading, but I just want to write this image with as little interference to the user's PC.  Can I access the raw USB drive starting from the first sector and just write the MBR followed by the two partitions of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you have sufficient privilege to do so, you can open a handle to write directly to a USB drive by using [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a filename like `\\.\PhysicalDrive2`.

You'll need to figure out the physical drive number.  If you have a drive letter, you can open a volume handle using a filename like `\\?\D:` and then use [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the physical drive number(s) associated with the volume.

You may need to dismount the existing volume (if any) first.  I'm not sure what the best approach is, but you could try using [`IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

*Edit:* here's some code I use for disk imaging, although I don't recall offhand whether I've ever tried it on a USB disk.  Public domain, but no warranty, express or implied, etc.  (Looking over the code I note that I haven't explicitly checked the sector size in order to make sure that the buffer and read/write operations are properly aligned.  This shouldn't be a problem in practice because the largest sector size in common use is 4K and this is also the memory page size on Windows.  However, in production code, you should always explicitly determine the sector size of the device in question and ensure proper alignment accordingly.)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define dump_buffersize_megs 16
#define dump_buffersize (dump_buffersize_megs * 1024 * 1024)
#define dump_workingsetsize ((dump_buffersize_megs + 1) * 1024 * 1024)

DWORD save(const wchar_t * source_device_name, const wchar_t * filename) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hdevice, houtput;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION source_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY source_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  hdevice = CreateFile
    (
    source_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (hdevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hdevice,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking input volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hdevice,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &source_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(source_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (source_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      hdevice,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &source_disklength,
      sizeof(source_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting input device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nInput disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    source_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      source_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      source_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      source_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Input device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated size will probably be incorrect, resulting\n"
      "in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Input disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    filename,
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u creating output file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(source_disklength.Length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hdevice, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hdevice, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output file.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
  overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

  if (!ReadFile(hdevice, buffer, source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector, NULL, &overlapped)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
    {
      printf("Save successfully completed.\n");      
      return 0;
    }
    printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!GetOverlappedResult(hdevice, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
    {
      printf("Save successfully completed.\n");      
      return 0;
    }
    printf("Error %u reading from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (byte_count == 0)
  {
    printf("Save successfully completed.\n"); 
    return 0;
  }

  printf("WARNING: the expected amount of data was successfully copied,\n"
         "but end of file not detected on input disk.  The copy might\n"
         "not be complete.");

  return ERROR_MORE_DATA;

}

DWORD write(const wchar_t * filename, const wchar_t * target_device_name) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hinput, houtput;

  WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  LARGE_INTEGER filelength;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION target_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY target_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER transfer_length;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!GetFileAttributesEx(filename, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u reading input file attributes.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  filelength.HighPart = fad.nFileSizeHigh;
  filelength.LowPart = fad.nFileSizeLow;

  fprintf(stderr, "\nInput file has %I64i bytes.\n", filelength.QuadPart);

  hinput = CreateFile
    (
    filename,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
    );

  if (hinput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    target_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening output device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &target_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(target_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (target_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      houtput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &target_disklength,
      sizeof(target_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    target_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      target_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      target_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      target_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      target_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Output device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated output device size is probably incorrect,\n"
      "which might result in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  if (filelength.QuadPart == target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    transfer_length.QuadPart = filelength.QuadPart;
  }
  else if (filelength.QuadPart < target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Image is smaller than target.  Part of the target will not be written to.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = filelength.QuadPart;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Image is larger than target.  Part of the image will not be copied.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = target_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating read from input file.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output disk.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  printf("Write successfully completed.\n");
  return 0;
}

DWORD clone(const wchar_t * source_device_name, const wchar_t * target_device_name) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hinput, houtput;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION source_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY source_diskgeometry;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION target_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY target_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER transfer_length;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  DWORD result;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  hinput = CreateFile
    (
    source_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (hinput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hinput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking input volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hinput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &source_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(source_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (source_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      hinput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &source_disklength,
      sizeof(source_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting input device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nInput disk has %I64i bytes.\n", source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    source_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      source_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      source_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      source_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Input device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated disk size is probably incorrect, resulting\n"
      "in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Input disk has %I64i bytes.\n",
      source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    target_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening output device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking output volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &target_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(target_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (target_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      houtput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &target_disklength,
      sizeof(target_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    target_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      target_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      target_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      target_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      target_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Output device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated output device size is probably incorrect,\n"
      "which might result in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart == target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    transfer_length.QuadPart = source_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }
  else if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart < target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    printf("Input shorter than output.  Part of the output disk will not be written to.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = source_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Output shorter than input.  Copy will be truncated to output length.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = target_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output disk.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  if (transfer_length.QuadPart == source_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
      {
        printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");      
        return 0;
      }
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
      {
        printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");
        return 0;
      }
      printf("Error %u reading from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count == 0)
    {
      printf("Copy successfully completed.\n"); 
      return 0;
    }

    printf("WARNING: the expected amount of data was successfully copied,\n"
           "but end of file not detected on input disk.  The copy might\n"
           "not be complete.");

    result = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");
  return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
  if (argc < 4)
  {
    printf("Syntax: \n"
      "To save an image of a physical drive:\n"
      "diskimage /save \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0 file.img\n"
      "diskimage /save \\\\.\\A: file.img\n"
      "To write from an image file to a physical drive:\n"
      "diskimage /write file.img \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0\n"
      "diskimage /write file.img \\\\.\\A:\n"
      "To clone input drive 0 to output drive 1:\n"
      "diskimage /clone \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0 \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1\n"
      );
    return 1;
  }
  if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/save") == 0)
  {
    return save(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/write") == 0)
  {
    return write(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/clone") == 0)
  {
    return clone(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Invalid argument.  Use /? for syntax help.\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this (on Win7 running as admin).  The calls to WriteFile succeed at first (I'm writing in chunks), but it seems like at some point shortly after the MBR is written,  I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED return code from WriteFile. I notice explorer has mounted the first partition. The same thing happens even if I start with a USB drive that has 0 partitions.  Here is the call where I open the USB for writing.

    HANDLE hHandleUSB = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1"),
      GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,
 NULL,
 OPEN_EXISTING,
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
 NULL);
<code>

Comment: You might need to use FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME rather than IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE as I originally suggested.  Also, did you remember the sector alignment requirements?  Operations have to be sector-aligned, and the operation length must be a multiple of the sector size; additionally, the address of the buffer in memory must be a multiple of the sector size.  I've added a copy of working code (not tested on USB, but it shouldn't be much different from a hard disk in this respect) so hopefully that will be some help.

Comment: Yup- I did FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME followed by FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME (not 100% sure if both are required), and it works!  Thanks.

Comment: I tried the above code, as administrator, on 64 bit Windows 7.

The device (second hard disk) to file `/save` worked fine.

The file to device `/write` failed with "Error 5 initiating write to output disk.".

It also caused "Microsoft Security Essentials" to pop up, offering to report the executable to Microsoft!

Comment: It did work fine, when I manually deleted the volume before doing the `/write`.  I think I just need to play with FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME.

Comment: Using FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME before FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME does not help.  FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME returns success, but the write still fails with error 5, as before.

Comment: Could the problem be that I am trying to unmount the whole disk, when what I want to do is unmount the partitions/filesystems/volumes on it?  (`umount /dev/sdb` vs `umount /dev/sdb1` on Linux.)

Comment: It works!  I had to FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME on `L"\\\\?\\E:"`, rather than `L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive2"`.