# Windows, opening a raw disk

Tags: c++, windows, raw-disk

I'm trying to read bytes from a raw disk.  (Windows 7, VS 2010.)

I get a value of -1 for hDisk (which I assume is an error).

How can I get the real data?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinIoCtl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    DWORD nRead;
    char buf[512];

    HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 
        GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,        
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    printf("hDisk %i\n", hDisk);

    SetFilePointer(hDisk, 0xA00, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(hDisk, buf, 512, &nRead, NULL);
    for (int currentpos=0;currentpos < 512;currentpos++) {
        std::cout << buf[currentpos];
    }
    CloseHandle(hDisk);
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastError? What did it return? I suspect you won't be able to do this unless you've admin rights.

Comment: Using `%i` to print a `HANDLE` is undefined behaviour. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) says that it's a `void *`, which means `%p` will work. Or you could just use `std::cout`. You also don't have to assume anything about the value. As per the documentation for `CreateFile`, you can compare it with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and call `GetLastError` for more information if they are equal.

Comment: Question is - What do you want to do? Write up a device driver, or to mount a specific volume?

Comment: Best to CreateFileW for L""

Comment: @chrisdew: Is CreateFile successful ? Check the returned handle. FILE_SHARE_READ alone may not be possible on PhysicalDrive0 which is C I assume ?

Comment: @Ajay read bytes from the raw disk, just for fun.

Comment: @RobH GetLastError returns 5.  Where do I look that up?  (Sorry, completely new to Windows.)

Comment: `5` means Access-Denied.

Comment: @chrisdew, You can find a link to the lists in the documentation for `GetLastError`. Visual Studio also comes with a utility where you can give it the number and get the data IIRC.

Comment: You can use `err` pseudo variable in Watch window to see last API status. You can use `err,hr` to see it with formatted-text. Use `variable, hr` in similar was to convert error-code to error string. User Tool->Error Lookup utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should I think work (when run with elevated privileges) except that:

- `buf[]` isn't properly aligned.
- Physical Drive 0 is likely to be the system drive, and hence in use.

Here's some code I use for disk imaging.  ([Previously posted here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013624/886887))  Public domain, but no warranty, express or implied, etc.  (Looking over the code I note that I haven't explicitly checked the sector size in order to make sure that the buffer and read/write operations are properly aligned.  This shouldn't be a problem in practice because the largest sector size in common use is 4K and this is also the memory page size on Windows.  However, in production code, you should always explicitly determine the sector size of the device in question and ensure proper alignment accordingly.)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define dump_buffersize_megs 16
#define dump_buffersize (dump_buffersize_megs * 1024 * 1024)
#define dump_workingsetsize ((dump_buffersize_megs + 1) * 1024 * 1024)

DWORD save(const wchar_t * source_device_name, const wchar_t * filename) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hdevice, houtput;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION source_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY source_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  hdevice = CreateFile
    (
    source_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (hdevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hdevice,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking input volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hdevice,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &source_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(source_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (source_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      hdevice,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &source_disklength,
      sizeof(source_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting input device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nInput disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    source_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      source_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      source_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      source_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Input device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated size will probably be incorrect, resulting\n"
      "in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Input disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    filename,
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u creating output file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(source_disklength.Length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hdevice, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hdevice, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output file.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
  overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

  if (!ReadFile(hdevice, buffer, source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector, NULL, &overlapped)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
    {
      printf("Save successfully completed.\n");      
      return 0;
    }
    printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!GetOverlappedResult(hdevice, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
    {
      printf("Save successfully completed.\n");      
      return 0;
    }
    printf("Error %u reading from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (byte_count == 0)
  {
    printf("Save successfully completed.\n"); 
    return 0;
  }

  printf("WARNING: the expected amount of data was successfully copied,\n"
         "but end of file not detected on input disk.  The copy might\n"
         "not be complete.");

  return ERROR_MORE_DATA;

}

DWORD write(const wchar_t * filename, const wchar_t * target_device_name) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hinput, houtput;

  WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  LARGE_INTEGER filelength;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION target_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY target_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER transfer_length;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!GetFileAttributesEx(filename, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u reading input file attributes.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  filelength.HighPart = fad.nFileSizeHigh;
  filelength.LowPart = fad.nFileSizeLow;

  fprintf(stderr, "\nInput file has %I64i bytes.\n", filelength.QuadPart);

  hinput = CreateFile
    (
    filename,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
    );

  if (hinput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input file.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    target_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening output device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &target_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(target_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (target_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      houtput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &target_disklength,
      sizeof(target_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    target_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      target_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      target_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      target_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      target_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Output device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated output device size is probably incorrect,\n"
      "which might result in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  if (filelength.QuadPart == target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    transfer_length.QuadPart = filelength.QuadPart;
  }
  else if (filelength.QuadPart < target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Image is smaller than target.  Part of the target will not be written to.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = filelength.QuadPart;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Image is larger than target.  Part of the image will not be copied.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = target_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating read from input file.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output disk.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  printf("Write successfully completed.\n");
  return 0;
}

DWORD clone(const wchar_t * source_device_name, const wchar_t * target_device_name) {

  DWORD err;

  HANDLE hinput, houtput;

  DWORD bytes_to_transfer, byte_count;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION source_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY source_diskgeometry;

  GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION target_disklength;

  DISK_GEOMETRY target_diskgeometry;

  LARGE_INTEGER transfer_length;

  LARGE_INTEGER offset;

  OVERLAPPED overlapped;

  BYTE * buffer;

  DWORD result;

  if (!SetProcessWorkingSetSize(GetCurrentProcess(), dump_workingsetsize, dump_workingsetsize)) 
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to expand working set.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dump_buffersize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

  if (buffer == NULL)
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to allocate buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!VirtualLock(buffer, dump_buffersize))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error %u trying to lock buffer.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  hinput = CreateFile
    (
    source_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (hinput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening input device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hinput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking input volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    hinput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &source_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(source_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (source_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      hinput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &source_disklength,
      sizeof(source_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting input device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nInput disk has %I64i bytes.\n", source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    source_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      source_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      source_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      source_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Input device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated disk size is probably incorrect, resulting\n"
      "in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Input disk has %I64i bytes.\n",
      source_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  houtput = CreateFile
    (
    target_device_name,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
    NULL
    );

  if (houtput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u opening output device.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u locking output volume.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  if (!DeviceIoControl
    (
    houtput,
    IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
    NULL,
    0,
    &target_diskgeometry,
    sizeof(target_diskgeometry),
    &byte_count,
    NULL
    ))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device geometry.\n", err);
    return err;
  }

  switch (target_diskgeometry.MediaType)
  {
  case Unknown:
  case RemovableMedia:
  case FixedMedia:

    if (!DeviceIoControl
      (
      houtput,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO,
      NULL,
      0,
      &target_disklength,
      sizeof(target_disklength),
      &byte_count,
      NULL
      ))
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %u getting output device length.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n\n", target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);
    break;

  default:

    target_disklength.Length.QuadPart = 
      target_diskgeometry.Cylinders.QuadPart *
      target_diskgeometry.TracksPerCylinder *
      target_diskgeometry.SectorsPerTrack *
      target_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector;

    fprintf(stderr, 
      "\n"
      "Output device appears to be a floppy disk.  WARNING: if this is not a\n"
      "floppy disk the calculated output device size is probably incorrect,\n"
      "which might result in an incomplete copy.\n"
      "\n"
      "Output disk has %I64i bytes.\n"
      "\n", 
      target_disklength.Length.QuadPart);

    break;
  }

  if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart == target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    transfer_length.QuadPart = source_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }
  else if (source_disklength.Length.QuadPart < target_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    printf("Input shorter than output.  Part of the output disk will not be written to.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = source_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Output shorter than input.  Copy will be truncated to output length.\n\n");
    transfer_length.QuadPart = target_disklength.Length.QuadPart;
  }

  offset.QuadPart = 0;
  overlapped.hEvent = 0;

  for (;;) 
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart < dump_buffersize) 
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = (DWORD)(transfer_length.QuadPart - offset.QuadPart);
      if (bytes_to_transfer == 0) break;
    }
    else
    {
      bytes_to_transfer = dump_buffersize;
    }

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u reading from input file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Internal error - partial read.  Last error code %u.\n", err);
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      if (byte_count == 0) return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
      bytes_to_transfer = byte_count;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(houtput, buffer, bytes_to_transfer, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
      {
        printf("Error %u initiating write to output disk.\n", err);
        return err;
      }
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(houtput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      printf("Error %u writing to output disk.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count != bytes_to_transfer)
    {
      printf("Internal error - partial write.\n");
      printf("bytes_to_transfer = %u; byte_count = %u.\n", bytes_to_transfer, byte_count);
      return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
    }

    offset.QuadPart += bytes_to_transfer;
  }

  if (transfer_length.QuadPart == source_disklength.Length.QuadPart)
  {
    overlapped.Offset = offset.LowPart;
    overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset.HighPart;

    if (!ReadFile(hinput, buffer, source_diskgeometry.BytesPerSector, NULL, &overlapped)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
      {
        printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");      
        return 0;
      }
      printf("Error %u initiating read from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hinput, &overlapped, &byte_count, TRUE)) 
    {
      err = GetLastError();
      if (err == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
      {
        printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");
        return 0;
      }
      printf("Error %u reading from input disk past end of file.\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    if (byte_count == 0)
    {
      printf("Copy successfully completed.\n"); 
      return 0;
    }

    printf("WARNING: the expected amount of data was successfully copied,\n"
           "but end of file not detected on input disk.  The copy might\n"
           "not be complete.");

    result = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Copy successfully completed.\n");
  return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
  if (argc < 4)
  {
    printf("Syntax: \n"
      "To save an image of a physical drive:\n"
      "diskimage /save \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0 file.img\n"
      "diskimage /save \\\\.\\A: file.img\n"
      "To write from an image file to a physical drive:\n"
      "diskimage /write file.img \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0\n"
      "diskimage /write file.img \\\\.\\A:\n"
      "To clone input drive 0 to output drive 1:\n"
      "diskimage /clone \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0 \\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1\n"
      );
    return 1;
  }
  if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/save") == 0)
  {
    return save(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/write") == 0)
  {
    return write(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else if (_wcsicmp(argv[1], L"/clone") == 0)
  {
    return clone(argv[2], argv[3]);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Invalid argument.  Use /? for syntax help.\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `CreateFile` clearly says:

> **Physical Disks and Volumes**
>
> Direct access to the disk or to a volume is restricted. For more
>   information, see "Changes to the file system and to the storage stack
>   to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access in Windows
>   Vista and in Windows Server 2008" in the Help and Support Knowledge
>   Base at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448.

IMO, there is no need to access the physical disk contents directly, unless you write a device driver.

**EDIT:**

To add some info to the Windows beginner developer: You need run your program **elevated**, even if you are logged in with Administrative rights. UAC controls this. You can make your program *always run elevated* by **Linker->Manifest File-> UAC Execution Level**, and set it to **requireAdministrator**. This is needed for any admin-rights task, as simple as `SetSystemTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the requireAdministrator hint.

Comment: There are valid use cases not associated with device drivers, including imaging or cloning disks, recovering deleted partitions, etc.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Can a developer write a version of "dd" that runs on 64 bit Windows 7+?  Would code signing be required?  Is the cost/process of signing only doable by corporations?  (P.S. I'm aware of http://www.chrysocome.net/dd but it talks about WinXP/2k.)

Comment: @chrisdew: no code signing is required.  I've already posted some working code for reading and writing to raw disk, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15013624/886887.