# Read specific sector on hard drive using C language on windows

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, boot

i have tried this code it works when i read a sector from an USB flash drive but it does'nt work with any partiton on hard drive , so i want to know if it's the same thing when you try to read from usb or from hard drive

```
int ReadSector(int numSector,BYTE* buf){

int retCode = 0;
BYTE sector[512];
DWORD bytesRead;
HANDLE device = NULL;

device = CreateFile("\\\\.\\H:",    // Drive to open
                    GENERIC_READ,           // Access mode
                    FILE_SHARE_READ,        // Share Mode
                    NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
                    OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
                    0,                      // File attributes
                    NULL);                  // Handle to template

if(device != NULL)
{
    SetFilePointer (device, numSector*512, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) ;

    if (!ReadFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        printf("Error in reading disk\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Copy boot sector into buffer and set retCode
        memcpy(buf,sector, 512);
        retCode=1;
    }

    CloseHandle(device);
    // Close the handle
}

return retCode;}
```

Comment: Which windows is it? Maybe it is just permissions issue.

Comment: Is USB drive FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: @EugeneSh. on windows 8.1

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez the usb use fat32

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez NTFS ..

Comment: Also you should check the handle against `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of `NULL`

Comment: As you may already know, NTFS was invented for security reasons. FAT32 is unsafe, while NTFS is strong safe. I believe that's why you can't access it.

Comment: is there any other solution to acces it ?

Comment: NTFS was made for you to NOT access it. For example, if you try to access C:\PROGRAM FILES, you will not be allowed. There is nothing you can do. This security is for our own good.

Comment: Don't be absurd, @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez.  Multiple programs associated with the OS access the hard disk, including at the behest of privileged users, so clearly it is possible.  There may be a permissions issue, but that's a far cry from "there's nothing you can do".

Comment: John Bollinger, show me the code to do it, I will test it here in my computer. NTFS blocks many many areas of the hard disk, for example, the partition table.

Comment: As a general principle, if you have logical I/O access to a drive, you have TOTAL control over that drive. If you have logical I/O access to a system drive, you have TOTAL control over the system. As shoddy as Windoze is, it is not going to let anyone do logical I/O to a drive in any form without having the appropriate privilege.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: in Windows 7, on a MBR computer, you can overwrite the partition table if you have administrator privilege.  Windows does not block you from doing so.  (I've just tried it, and it works.)  You can also write into NTFS partitions, though of course you have to dismount them first.  Some code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27135530/886887

Comment: (Also, of course, you *can* write stuff into Program Files, you just have to have administrator privilege.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the sharing mode.  You have specified `FILE_SHARE_READ` which means that nobody else is allowed to write to the device, but the partition is already mounted read/write so it isn't possible to give you that sharing mode.  If you use `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE` it will work.  (Well, provided the disk sector size is 512 bytes, and provided the process is running with administrator privilege.)

You're also checking for failure incorrectly; CreateFile returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure rather than `NULL`.

I tested this code successfully:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int retCode = 0;
    BYTE sector[512];
    DWORD bytesRead;
    HANDLE device = NULL;
    int numSector = 5;

    device = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:",    // Drive to open
                        GENERIC_READ,           // Access mode
                        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,        // Share Mode
                        NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
                        OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
                        0,                      // File attributes
                        NULL);                  // Handle to template

    if(device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    SetFilePointer (device, numSector*512, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) ;

    if (!ReadFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        printf("ReadFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```