# How to read something to the RAW disk and then write it some further in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, filesystems, disk

I'd like to first write something to a disk device, then read the same data and write it some further. My code looks like this:

```
std::string devicePath = "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"; //'0' is only example here
HANDLE source = CreateFile(disk.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);

    BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE(source, "Failed to create file handle.");

        std::unique_ptr<CHAR[]> primaryBuffer(new CHAR[DEFAULT_FILESIZE]);
        std::unique_ptr<CHAR[]> checkBuffer(new CHAR[DEFAULT_FILESIZE]);

        for (auto i = 0; i < DEFAULT_FILESIZE; ++i) {
            primaryBuffer[i] = 'x';
            checkBuffer[i] = ' ';
        }

        WriteFile(source, primaryBuffer.get(), DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, NULL);

//Here I move the pointer to write data in new place.
        DWORD destination = SetFilePointer(source, DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);           
        WriteFile(&destination, source, DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, NULL);

        ReadFile(source, primaryBuffer.get(), DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, NULL);
        ReadFile(&destination, checkBuffer.get(), DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, NULL);

        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(checkBuffer.get());
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(primaryBuffer.get());
```

Unfortunately, both buffers are different and I've tried almost everything to check what's wrong. Maybe somebody has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Passing `&destination` as the 1. argument to  `WriteFile()` looks pretty nonsensical,as does passing `source` as 2. argument of WriteFile. What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: @nos I was trying to copy content from address `source` (I know that this is `HANDLE`) to address `destination`. I'm not sure if I was passing address correctly

Comment: But your `destination`  variable  is just a return value from SetFilePointer() ? It doesn't make any sense to pass that as the handle that WriteFile() requires. Also if you want to read data from one handle and write it to another handle , you need to do it in 2 steps, read into a buffer, write that buffer to the other handle. Please refer to the WriteFile documentation.

Comment: OK, that's clear for me, but I don't understand how I can create new handle moved by a few bytes related to the first one

Comment: Physical Drive 0 is likely to be the system drive, and hence in use. [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063419/windows-opening-a-raw-disk)

Comment: @okocki Are you trying to copy data from the same "file" to the same "file" ? Maybe you don't need a new handle, you could just use the one handle you have. Open the "file". Read the data into a buffer. Call SetFilePointer() to move the handle where you need it. Write the buffer.

Comment: I wrote 0 only for example purpose, that's not drive which I'm using in my code

Comment: `WriteFile(&destination, source` - of course error. you not need use `SetFilePointer` at all, but direct pass offset in `OVERLAPPED`. all read/write data size and offsets must be aligned on sector size. you not check errors - are say `WriteFile` failed. in your code it failed 100%

Comment: and `ReadFile(&destination, ` - what is this ?? typo ?

Comment: for what you `SetFilePointer` at all ? this is primary senseless api. need direct pass offset in `OVERLAPPED`

Comment: and in your code you *try* write to file and then *try* read from file from different positions at all

Comment: @nos I think I'm starting to see where my mistake is... I read documentation for SetFilePointer and found nothing about changing handle in this function. What exactly should I do to change my handle? I guess I should do something with return value from function, but I don't know what exactly

Comment: @RbMm I have no idea how to create (or pass something as) `OVERLAPPED` structure to offset handle

Comment: very easy `OVERLAPPED ov = {};
  ov.Offset = *;
  ov.OffsetHigh = *;
  WriteFile(*, &ov)` and are you understand what is file handle ? `ReadFile(&destination` and `WriteFile(&destination` what is this ??

Comment: @RbMm you don't have to write in this sarcastic style. I've tried to use `WriteFile(source, primaryBuffer.get(), DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, &ov);` (to check if anything changed) and then `ReadFile(source, checkBuffer.get(), DEFAULT_FILESIZE, NULL, &ov);` , but that also won't work

Comment: are you check errors - are WriteFile and ReadFile returns true ? if not what is GetLastError ?

Comment: @okocki, the only thing you need to do with the return value from SetFilePointer is to check whether the call succeeded or not.  Each handle has a file pointer associated with it, and when you do a read or a write with that handle, the file pointer is the default location in the file for the read or write.  (You can override that default by passing an OVERLAPPED structure.)  So when you call SetFilePointer you are changing the state of the handle you pass to it, it doesn't give you a new handle.

Comment: This does seem like a case where using OVERLAPPED would be simpler.  If you edit the question and add the version of the code that tries to use OVERLAPPED we can advise what is going wrong.  Make sure to include error handling.  One thing to check is that `DEFAULT_FILESIZE` is a multiple of the drive's sector size, which is probably either 512 or 4096.  I/O on raw disk must be sector-aligned.  You may also need to create sector-aligned buffers, e.g., using `VirtualAlloc` rather than `new`.  Oh, and if the disk has a mounted file system on it you may need `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME`.