# Modify bytes in volume to restore deleted files using c++

Tags: c++, operating-system

How can I get access to Volume (like USB) then modify bytes to restore my deleted files?

I used these lines of code however, it can only access the existed files in that volume but the whole volume's byte array

```
//Edit item at 0000000D '00' to '01'
fstream binaryFile("E:/txt.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
binaryFile.seekp(0x0D);
binaryFile << char(0x01);  
binaryFile.close();
```

then I don't know if I could access my volume E:\ using this

```
fstream binaryFile("E:", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Please help, this exercise is important to me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063419/windows-opening-a-raw-disk

Comment: I think this shows me what I should work with is WriteFile function, I searched for hours but nothing was clear, can you recommend some more references