# How to use ReadFile() in c++ to read bytes of length that are not multiple of 512

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to read raw bytes to a drive. But the function ReadFile() only allowing me to read bytes of length 512 or its multiple. I cannot read bytes of length 10, 180,1000 etc.

```
DWORD NumberOfBytesRead=0;

ReadFile(hDevice, nullbuffer, (DWORD)512, &NumberOfBytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL); //works

ReadFile(hDevice, nullbuffer, (DWORD)1024, &NumberOfBytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL); //works

ReadFile(hDevice, nullbuffer, (DWORD)1000, &NumberOfBytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL); //error 87

ReadFile(hDevice, nullbuffer, (DWORD)300, &NumberOfBytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);  //error 87
```

Is there some way to overcome this?

Comment: So are you reading or writing? Also, having you considered  using the standard C++ library instead of Windows' API?

Comment: @ein: The C++ Standard Library only provides interfaces to access the file system. It doesn't offer any services that allow you to write directly to a disk.

Comment: I am reading  not writing. And C++ standard library provides no method to read raw bytes directly from a drive not the files in it.

Comment: So is the 'multiple of 512 bytes' issue a limitation of the underlying device rather than the API itself?

Comment: its because of the device. I am trying to read raw bytes from a usb drive of 32GB

Comment: Seems like you need to create your own buffer. Read from the buffer (as many bytes as you like) but when the buffer is empty fill it by reading from the device in multiples of 512.

Comment: @IInspectable, I am reading

Comment: @john ok that is a nice idea.. I can definitely do that. If I am unable to find any other idea then I will use your idea.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004984/how-to-write-an-image-containing-multiple-partitions-to-a-usb-flash-drive-on-win/15013624#15013624

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and tell us what kind of device it is. Please don't add relevant parts as comments, but edit your question to provide the additional information. Thanks.

Comment: @WernerHenze We don't need to know what type of device it is. The rules apply to all direct access of a disk device.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The original post does not mention that it is a disk device, so I was asking to add this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for direct access of the device mandate that you must read aligned blocks of data. That's not something that you can change. It's a hard rule that you must follow.

Given this rule, you must read into a buffer that is a multiple of the required block size. If you wish only to access some part of that buffer, you can pick that part out after you have read from the device.